# Magento 2.3: Klarna + Coupon Code results in "main.ERROR:Order line totals do not total order_amount"

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, magento2.3.3, klarna, magento2.3.4

Klarna Payment method is activated in the checkout. It works fine as long as you don't use a coupon code. If you do, the checkout page breaks with the following error:

> main.ERROR:Order line totals do not total order_amount - 530 != 490

**Here is what I did already:**

- Deactivated ALL third party modules
- Activated Luma Standard Theme
- Deactivated all other payment methods
- Went through the database in the hope to find anything
- Tested different tax and pricing settings
- Updated from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4

**Does anybody have an idea what I could have missed?
Or what I should test next?**

Using Magento 2.3.3 (live) and 2.3.4 (dev). Happens on both instances. Live and Dev are located on different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by setting the "Apply customer Tax" to "Before Discount":

Shop => Configuration => Sales => Tax

Standard Setting is:

[image]

Now I receive a Magento Warning in the backend. But at least everything works.
Still, I think there is something wrong with Klarna Payment.

Comment: I find difficulty around refreshing placements for configurable products. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: I can try. Could you please explain what you mean by placements?

Comment: Hello Stefan, placements are the tags meant to display the Klarna tagline for Pay Over Time benefit. I have moved past this particular stage to what is explained at my latest post. please see if you can help based on your prior experience. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312998/in-jquery-how-to-capture-the-html-when-the-product-price-changes

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.klarna.com/assets/sites/15/2020/03/04081615/user_guides.pdf page 15

This is proper M2 tax configuration to work with Klarna

**General Tax Calculation**

- “Tax Calculation Based On” should be set to “Shipping Address”
- “Apply Customer Tax” must be set to “After Discount”

**Tax Calculation for non-US countries**

- “Tax Calculation Method Based On” should be set to “Row Total”
- “Catalog Prices” must be set to “Including Tax”
- “Shipping Prices” must be set to “Including Tax”
- “Apply Discount on Prices” must be set to “Including Tax”

**Tax Calculation for US**

- “Tax Calculation Method Based On” should be set to “Unit Price”
- “Catalog Prices” must be set to “Excluding Tax”
- “Shipping Prices” must be set to “Excluding Tax”
- “Apply Discount on Prices” must be set to “Excluding Tax”

Comment: I find difficulty around refreshing placements for configurable products. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Thank you. @Hypo

Answer (score 0):

Klarna\Core\Model\Checkout\Orderline\Items;

private function processItem($product, $item, $qtyMultiplier)

Modify the processItem function

```
private function processItem($product, $item, $qtyMultiplier)
{ .....
if ($this->klarnaConfig->isSeparateTaxLine($item->getStore())) {
  ......
} else {
   .......
      $_item['total_amount'] = $this->helper->toApiFloat(
       ($item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) + $item->getBaseTaxAmount()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/mage2pro/klarna/issues/8) for this issue - up to now it's not solved yet, however.

The following patch should help:

```
diff --git a/Model/Checkout/Orderline/Items.php b/Model/Checkout/Orderline/Items.php
index dd77db9..ebb8640 100644
--- a/Model/Checkout/Orderline/Items.php
+++ b/Model/Checkout/Orderline/Items.php
@@ -156,7 +156,7 @@ class Items extends AbstractLine
         $_item['unit_price'] = $this->helper->toApiFloat($item->getBasePrice())
             ?: $this->helper->toApiFloat($item->getBaseOriginalPrice());
         $_item['total_amount'] = $this->helper->toApiFloat(
-                $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()
+                $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $item->getBaseDiscountTaxCompensationAmount()
         );
     } else {
         $_item['tax_rate'] = $this->helper->toApiFloat($item->getTaxPercent());
```